# Why is the output undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Can you elaborate whats happening in my code? Why its undefined?

```js
let room = {
  width: '100',
  height: '200',
  findTemp: function() {
    console.log("temp is 28");
  }
}
var newRoom = room.findTemp;
console.log(newRoom());
```

Comment: Because you don't `return` anything from the `findTemp` function.

Answer (score 6):

You're not actually returning anything from the function, so the value returned by the function will be `undefined`. Therefore, when you run `console.log()`, that's what it will display. You also don't need to log twice. To solve this, you can either remove the `console.log()` from the function definition and just return the string:

```
let room = {
  width: '100',
  height: '200',
  findTemp: function() {
    return "temp is 28";
  }
}
let newRoom = room.findTemp;
console.log(newRoom());
```

Or, you can just call the function:

```
let room = {
  width: '100',
  height: '200',
  findTemp: function() {
    console.log("temp is 28");
  }
}
let newRoom = room.findTemp;
newRoom();
```

Comment: I've also changed your `var` to a `let`